# Setting Color property by using BoolToObjectConverter

Tags: maui, syncfusion, maui-community-toolkit

I want to set a background color by a boolean property *IsCurrentPage*.
That for I use the community toolkit *BoolToObjectConverter* like that:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
    <toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter x:Key="BoolToColorConverter" TrueObject="Colors.Red" FalseObject="Colors.Blue"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

At my implementation it looks so:

```xml
<syncfusion:SfChip Text="{Binding IsCurrentPage, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}" 
                   BackgroundColor="{Binding IsCurrentPage, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}" 
                   TextColor="Black"/>
```

The Text at the Buttons is correct. (e.g. "Colors.Red")
But the background color is always white (default).
I tried also "Red" instead of "Colors.Red".

**Why the background color is not set properly?**

Answer (score 4):

You're passing `"Colors.Red"` and `"Colors.Blue"`, which are of type `string` and not `Color` objects in this case.

In order to pass the `Colors.Red` and `Colors.Blue` objects, try the following instead:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
    <toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter
        x:Key="BoolToColorConverter"
        TrueObject="{x:Static Colors.Red}"
        FalseObject="{x:Static Colors.Blue}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Alternative:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
    <toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter x:Key="BoolToColorConverter">
        <toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter.TrueObject>
            <Color>Red</Color>
        </toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter.TrueObject>
        <toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter.FalseObject>
            <Color>Blue</Color>
        </toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter.FalseObject>
    </toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

Julian is right. The color is to set as x:Static.
Also at Syncfusion Chip the background color has the property name Background (without *color*).

```
<toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter x:Key="BoolToColorConverter" 
                               TrueObject="{x:Static Colors.Red}"
                               FalseObject="{x:Static Colors.White}"/>

<syncfusion:SfChip Text="{Binding Title}" 
                   Background="{Binding IsCurrentPage, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}"
                   TextColor="Black" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with passing the arguments (TrueObject and FalseObject) of the BoolToObjConverter for the SfChip control's BackgroundColor property. The original code used string values ("Colors.Red" and "Colors.Blue") as the arguments, but the BackgroundColor property expects Color objects.

The corrected code snippet is as follows:
​​
**Code Snippet:**

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
            <toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter x:Key="BoolToColorConverter"   TrueObject="{x:Static Colors.Red}" FalseObject="{x:Static Colors.Blue}"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>




<syncfusion:SfChip Text="{Binding IsCurrentPage,Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter }}"
                              
                   BackgroundColor="{Binding IsCurrentPage,Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter },Mode=TwoWay}"
                               TextColor="Black"
                   />
```

By using "{x:Static Color.Red}" and "{x:Static Color.Blue}", Passing Color objects directly to the TrueObject and FalseObject properties of the BoolToObjConverter, which are expected by the BackgroundColor property of the SfChip control.

The Mode=TwoWay attribute in the BackgroundColor binding indicates that changes made to the BackgroundColor in the UI will also update properly.